# Can anyone explain why following series is absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $r < 1, K \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $|X_n|^{1/n} < r$ for all $n > K$, then the series $X_n$ (Summation of $X_n$ from $n$ to $\infty$) is absolutely convergent.

We know that  $|X_n| < r^n$ for all $n > K$ so sum of all terms would be bounded by sum of finite terms up to $k-1$ and sum of geometric series. Thus, this is bounded above and increasing $\implies$ convergent.

However, How can I show that this is absolutely convergent by using Cauchy Criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia: [Cauchy's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test)

You have $|X_{n+1}+X_{n+2}+\cdots+X_{n+p}| \leq |X_{n+1}|+\cdots+|X_{n+p}| \leq r^{n+1}+\cdots+r^{n+p} = r^{n+1}(1+r+\cdots+r^{p-1}) = r^{n+1}\dfrac{1-r^p}{1-r} < \dfrac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

Choosing $N$ sufficiently large, we can guarantee that $\dfrac{r^{n+1}}{1-r} < \epsilon$ for any $n \geq N$.

*Edit:* Depending on your audience, you might be expected to actually specify $N$. If so, essentially solve $\dfrac{r^{N+1}}{1-r}=\epsilon$ for $N$.

We get: $\epsilon(1-r)=r^{N+1}$ so $\ln(\epsilon(1-r)) = (N+1)\ln(r)$ and so $N+1 = \dfrac{\ln(\epsilon(1-r))}{\ln(r)}$. So if you choose $N=\left\lceil{\dfrac{\ln(\epsilon(1-r))}{\ln(r)}}\right\rceil$, then $N$ will be large enough to make the inequalities work.

Comment: Do I need to specify how large N should be ?

Comment: For Large N, how do we know N is larger than K or K is larger than N?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you used a bracket for N?

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound lazy, but once one is comfortable with the concepts of these proofs, one doesn't always have to specify the exact formula the find the N in terms of epsilon.  The idea of a "sufficiently large" n and m is enough if you can see the whole thing shrinks faster than the n, m get large.

Comment: The bracket just means the next integer that is bigger.  The idea is that if you choose something "large enough" finding the exact precise value where it becomes precisely big enough after not being big enough isn't really that important.  They idea is we are going to be picking really huge numbers; we'll pick them safely huge.  It's like saying "well we are all going to die sometime" "Oh, yeah? when?"  "I dunno, let's just say 500 years, that's big enough" rather than saying "Well, I'm fifty and you are 20 so the average life span is 70 but some live longer so 93.4 years, carry the two, 95.2"

Answer (score 0):

$\sum |X_n| \lt \sum r^n$.  If$\sum r^n$ converges then $\sum|X_n$| converges so $\sum X_n$ converges absolutely.

To show $\sum r^2n$ converge by the Cauchy Criteria we only have to show {$\sum_N r^n$} is a Cauchy sequence. As $\sum_N r^n - \sum_M r^n$ = $r^{M+1} + r^{M+2} +...+ r^N$ = $r^{M+1}(1 + r^2 + ... + r^{v = N - M - 1})$ = $r^{M+1}(1 - r^{v+1})/(1 - r) < r^{M+1}/(1 -r) < \epsilon$  for an appropriately epsilon and M, N large enough. So is a Cauchy sequence.

====

Okay so for epsilon what K do we choose that N,M > K lead to this?  0 < r < 1 so $r^n$ is decreasing so for $\epsilon$ < 0, there is a K such that $0 < e^K < \epsilon$.  Then if N > M > K our result will follow.

Comment: Did you choose N to be larger than K?

Comment: Also, After we find out how Large M should be for epsilon, how can I guarantee that N is larger than K?

Comment: I was sloppy and lazy as I figured the idea of epsilon N proofs were general and the real issue was under standing the definitions and consequences.  Yes, we'll need to tweak it.